# Maximum no. of posts added to favourites list per day

Tags: support, bookmarks, rate-limiting

What is the maximum number of posts that can be added to favourites list by an user on a single day?

Comment: I don't think this action is rate limited. Trying to look for a source though.

Comment: [4,451,521?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest). By the time you read this comment the number will have increased. I wouldn't recommend it though and the devs might complain.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, I think it's not a duplicate, since this qn is about per day

Comment: @Azik but the answer there also answer your question: "no limit", which also implies no limit per day. Saw that other question only after answering here though.

Comment: anyway I got the answer for my qn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all actions are rate limited, only actions which either can lead to abuse or are "expensive" in the code behind e.g. take resources from the server.

Adding a question to your favorites list is a simple action which can't really be abused so it's not rate limited.

Complete list of rate limited actions can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/152859).

Comment: Should that be "expensive", or does this feature take up 10000+ lines of code? ;-)

Comment: @Jon I will go after you with a huge "E"! (but yeah, good point ;))